# Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BackgroundDetector.readCurrentStateIfPossible

Tags: android, crash, google-play-services

I got lots of this on Android 4.0.4 where `android.app.ActivityManager.getMyMemoryState` is missing method.

And full stack trace is:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.app.ActivityManager.getMyMemoryState
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BackgroundDetector.readCurrentStateIfPossible(Unknown Source:17)
       at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.handleMessage(Unknown Source:169)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.base.zap.dispatchMessage(Unknown Source:8)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65
```

My gms related dependencies is:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:16.0.0'
```

+ firebase:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:16.2.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.3'
```

Which seem to be up to date (at time of writing)

Is there anything I can do to prevent those crashes?

Comment: Do you have any Firebase libraries as well? I've noticed this when I upgraded all of my Firebase and GMS libs (15.x -> 16.x). It's been hard to determine which one caused the issue b/c the crash is intermittent. I've noticed on my Android 4 device that it crashes a couple times but the app will eventually run find on the 2nd or 3rd bootup.

Comment: Yes. I also use:  firebase-core:16.0.7, firebase-perf:16.2.3 and firebase-ads:17.1.3

Comment: Looks like a  `ViewCompat` problem **min sdk version?** You **really** tie our hands when you do not provide the full build.gradle files.

Comment: @JonGoodwin, Sorry, I through I provide enough information, here is a full [build.gradle](https://github.com/NYRDS/remixed-dungeon/blob/198b43d30ce15e8574408ab077cf938573ff0f5e/RemixedDungeon/build.gradle)

Comment: @Jsyntax, I'm not yet sure, but probably I located issue: in `play-services-base:16.1.0` `com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.BackgroundDetector.readCurrentStateIfPossible` checks API level to be at least Jelly Bean before attempt to call `android.app.ActivityManager.getMyMemoryState` (which in turn introduced in Jelly Bean) But in 16.1.0 `PlatformVersion.isAtLeastJellyBean` return true regardless of actual android API level. So I downgraded to `play-services-base:16.0.1`. Crashlytics registered no crashes so far with downgraded `play-services-base`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I located the source of this issue:

`play-services-base:16.1.0` assume it runs on at least JellyBean (API level 16) OS (I found this with help of Android Studio java decompiler (`PlatformVersion.isAtLeastJellyBean` just unconditionally return true.)), which, is not true in my case.

So I downgraded to `play-services-base:16.1.0` to `play-services-base:16.0.1` and crashes was stopped.

Comment: Should this be fixed by Google? I cannot go back to older libraries. I tried logging a bug on their site but it's so intuitive (Google Groups) and I am sure if it was recorded correctly. If anyone can report this to Google, it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Jsyntax I hope so. But only solution I can think of for now: is to create separate build flavor for old devices without play-services.

Comment: My use of `implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'` appears to use `play-services-base:16.1.0` - but I need that library for a search location feature. I am stuck with this.

Comment: I had to downgrade `firebase-core` from `16.0.8` to `16.0.7` since `16.0.8` depends on `play-services-basement:16.2.0` which (silently) assumes API level 16.

Answer (score 2):

Until the problem is not solved by Google, just use and force play-services-basement:16.0.1

```
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1"

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force "com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:16.0.1"
}
```

Comment: Your solution looks better than my. I will try it in the wild.

Comment: But it turns out badly in my case, immediately new crash appeared: 

Fatal Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.android.gms.common.internal.Preconditions.checkHandlerThread
       at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.GmsClientEventManager.onConnectionSuccess(Unknown Source:20)
       ...
       ...